# Insert at specific location of a 2d vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a 2d vector which represents a 2d grid; so `grid[0][2]` for example. I am needing to 'insert' *-might not be the right word here.* a vector at a specific location say `grid[3][2]` there will definitely be a `grid[0][0]` but when im needing to *insert* into `grid[3][2]` there may be nothing before it other than `grid[0][0]` and there needs to be the space in between for later on. Is there any way to do this?

Thank you for your help.

*ps: I should note that the size of the vectors are not known (they will grow over time)*

Comment: If the array is smaller than your needs, resize it and then do the insert.

Comment: @Robinson I need to reference the grid as `grid[3][2]` otherwise, I wouldn't know where X3 Y2 is located if it was pushed to `grid[0][1]`

Comment: No, I mean literally if you see that x,y does not exist in the array as it isn't large enough, resize the array until it's large enough to store x,y and then store x,y :p.

Comment: @Robinson sorry I didn't get what you were saying, but Thanks anyway! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your requirements correctly, but:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> grid(4);  // 4 rows

grid[3].resize(3)  // resize 4th row

grid[3][2] = 42;
```

Your 2D grid would then "look" like that:

```
 |
 - 
 |
 -                  <---  3 empty rows
 |
 --------------
 | 0 | 0 | 42 |
 --------------
```

You can freely resize the rows later on. Note that there is row 0, but no [0][0] element just yet, you have to add it yourself.

Comment: Yes.  That is what I meant :p.

Comment: @jrok interesting, It seems I'm a little confused; I may need to brush up on my knowledge. So am I correct at saying that I could reference `grid[3][0] / grid[3][1] and grid[3][2]` but not `grid[2][0]` (until I created it)

Comment: which I would `grid[2].resize(1)`

Comment: @Elgoog, yes that's correct. Note that `grid[0]` is valid - it's an empty vector.