# OpenCV create Matrix containing multiple images in each row

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I need to create a data-matrix of images in OpenCV. Basically each row of the matrix will contain multiple images of the same person. I found this [asRowMatrix tutorial](http://www.bytefish.de/blog/pca_in_opencv) written by @
bytefish, however I do not currently understand how I would copy multiple images into a row of the Matrix. I have a text file of image paths, separated by ";" when the paths are referring to a new subject, eg:

```
Subject1/Image1.png
Subject1/Image2.png
;
Subject2/Image1.png
```

My initial idea was to have a 2D vector:

```
Vector<Vector<Mat>> intra;
    while(file.good()) {
    getline(file, path);
    if((path.compare(";"))!=0){
        try{
 //Add images to person-index
            intra[curRow].push_back(imread(path,0));
        } catch (Exception const & e){
            cerr<<"OpenCV exception: "<<e.what()<<std::endl;
        }
    } else{
//";" found --> increment person-index
        curRow++;
    }
}
imshow("Intra[0,0]",intra[0][0]);
```

However, I'm getting an error which I believe is due to the vector not being of size(curRow+1)

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (i < size()) in unknown function, file c:\opencv\
include\opencv2\core\operations.hpp, line 2357
OpenCV exception: c:\opencv\include\opencv2\core\operations.hpp:2357: error: (-2
15) i < size()
```

Resizing the vector in the else did not solve the issue! Any pointers on solving this problem or using a different OpenCV datastructure would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using push_back I decided to dynamically resize the vector each time I add an image. This might be inefficient, however it solves the problem of the incorrect reference. I got the idea by [@jrok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122293/insert-at-specific-location-of-a-2d-vector) answer to a 2D vector element access [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122293/insert-at-specific-location-of-a-2d-vector). Edited solution:

```
int curRow=0;
int numImages=0;

string line, path, temp;
while(file.good()) {
    getline(file, path);
    if((path.compare(";"))!=0){
        try{
            faces[curRow].resize(numImages+1);
            faces[curRow][numImages] = imread(path,0);
            numImages++;
        } catch (Exception const & e){
            cerr<<"OpenCV exception: "<<e.what()<<std::endl;
        }
    } else{
        numImages=0;
        curRow++;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps other people facing the same problem!